# No access from foreign IP to Minecraft server

Tags: server, firewall, minecraft, nat, windows-firewall

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBAaT.png]

### Overview

This is a general error, but I'm unable to locate the problem and hence solution. I'm hosting a Minecraft server on my **localhost** (`192.168.0.2`) on port `25565`. It *can* be accessed from the host by its **internal IP** (**localhost** and `192.168.0.2`) but is unable to be accessed from the **external IP** (`101.xxx.xx.xx`).

### Have you tried turning it on and off again?

Yes. I've restarted my host. Also the server says

> `[14:32:14] [Server thread/INFO] [net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565`

so it must be true.

### Port Forwarded?

I can verify that the port ***is open*** to HTTP through a simple Node.JS server hosted on the device. This **can** be accessed on through `101.xxx.xx.xx:25565` on my mobile device on the same network but *times-out* on the browser of the host. Moreover, it is forwarded on both **TCP** and **UDP**.

[image: Proof of UDP and TCP forward]

```
const { createServer } = require('http')

createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('Request', req.url)
    res.end('Ok')
}).listen(25565)
```

### Firewalls

Additionally, I modified my firewalls: Windows and antivirus. I turned off *Avast Web Shield* which blocks foreign unrecognized internet connections and followed both these tutorials to add [firewall exceptions for Java](https://youtu.be/watch?v=68ZWYAuqsmY) and [port exceptions](https://youtu.be/5VrxwRM2Wg4?t=561). I allowed my Telstra Arcadyan **modem** to keep its firewall because I could still access my internal network from a foreign address.

### Wireshark and Nmap

I suspected that the internal connection was the issue so I used **nmap**. I ran it on the host and another device on the network, my Raspberry Pi (192.168.0.69).

**On my Raspberry Pi**, `nmap -p 25565 -T4 -Pn -A -v 192.168.0.2` on my raspberry pi (`192.168.0.69`) returned

> `25565/tcp open  minecraft Minecraft 1.12.2 (Protocol: 127, Message: Rebirth of the Night! (Optifine 1.12.2), Users: 0/6)`

Additionally the *same command* but with a different destination (WAN IP), returned the same message.

**On my host Windows device**, the result was identical for the internal IP (192.168.0.2), but the external IP (101.xxx.xx.xx) returned `filtered`. This is primarily why I believe there is a firewall in the way.

> `25565/tcp filtered minecraft`

Host - Local Address

[image: Host Local]

Host - Foreign Address

[image: Host Foreign]

Raspberry Pi - Local Address

[image: RasPi Local]

Raspberry Pi - Foreign Address

[image: RasPi Foreign]

## Summary

I suspect it must be because of an inbound connection to firewall issue due to my trials with **nmap** and **wireshark**. Sadly, I'm unable to locate it. Am I missing something?

#### Update

The answer might be [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT). though I'm not certain. It might be a **NAT Loopback** problem.

#### Footnotes

- The server is *[Rebirth of the Night v2.76.2](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/rebirth-of-the-night)*
- There is no server logging when I try to connect from the external address i.e. no evidence of a connection attempt
- There are other servers on this LAN
- [MC Server Status](https://mcsrvstat.us/server/) returns the correct information. (The server is visible)
- [This article](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/Arcadyan-LH1000-Port-forwarding/td-p/827106) gives the possibility that the internal to external to internal connection is the problem.

  > "The LH1000 does not support NAT which means that even if the ports are open you can not connect to a device on your network from another device on your network using the public address of the modem and the port number of the device."
- When doing the testing below, I did not invoke the Node.JS and the MC server concurrently.
- This somewhat resembles the problem where I **cannot ssh to my raspberry pi from the external ip** (`101.xxx.xx.xx`). I can *only* connected to it through the internal ip (`192.168.0.69`)
  [image: PuTTY error]
- This is the log from the Minecraft game output
  [image: Minecraft Game Log - io.netty.channel]
- As a side note, **Wireshark** with the filter `udp.port == 25565 || tcp.port == 25565` had three different outputs.

For the **Node.JS** HTTP server accessed from a mobile device with VPN, it output
[image]

For the **Node.JS** HTTP server accessed from the host device, it output
[image]

For the **Minecraft** server, it output
[image]

Comment: Wow this is the most thorough and detailed question I have seen for a long time. This is such a breath of fresh air from _givez me teh codez_. Perhaps this can add to the fact finding mission: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ - testing open ports from yet another external host. If that says the port is open then maybe it's an out going thing from the client. To simulate a true external host you could also run up a free VM in a cloud provider and test from there

Comment: My friend has tested from 3 different addresses (nmap) with 'open' as the result, but he has yet to connect through a Minecraft client. With the Node server active, [yougetsignal.com](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) returns positive. I've noted [this article](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/Arcadyan-LH1000-Port-forwarding/td-p/827106) which states "The LH1000 does not support NAT", so I cannot connect to it from the same network. In all likelihood, that's the issue. I will see once my friend attempts connecting. Thanks for the compliment tho.

Comment: Could it have something to do with a router between your system and the internet? How many other servers are on your network? What happens if you turn some/all of them off? You could try turning them off and running your server over their port and see if that works.

Comment: I have HTTP and HTTPS servers running on a different host. While I see no reason for it to affect this host,
I shut down the Raspberry Pi (the other host) and hosted the minecraft server on port 80. I also port-forwarded to my host. With `192.168.0.2:80`, I received a valid connection, but still met the same error. `nmap -p 80 -T4 -pn 101.xxx.xx.xx` on the **host** returned `filtered`. Thanks for trying to help :). I believe the issue is with [this](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT) @Luctia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## NAT Loopback (Hairpinning)

My router (Telstra Arcadyan LH1000) doesn't support NAT loop back, where the external address of the network can be accessed from an internal IP. It rewrites the connection directly to the other network address (itself in my case) which the client rejects because it doesn't expect the rewrite.

### Solutions

There are two solutions: **a masquerade NAT rule** which most routers do not support and **using the internal IP**. Additionally, upgrading router firmware may solve the issue, but it's unlikely. In my case, the Technicolor modem has *[full NAT loop back support](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/Arcadyan-LH1000-0-09-11r-any-update-on-NAT-loopback/td-p/854953)*, but I'm unable to get one.

#### [Solution 1](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT)

This rule should be added to the router (accessible at something like `192.168.0.1`).

```
/ip firewall nat
    add chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.1.0/24 \
    dst-address=192.168.1.2 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \
    out-interface=LAN action=masquerade
```

#### Solution 2

This is not a resolution of the problem but merely avoidance of the issue. The Minecraft server can be accessed on `localhost` and `192.168.0.2` but not on the external IP.

#### Solution?

The network address can be reached from a different adapter. If the port-forward is to Wi-Fi (distinct from the Ethernet adapter), then an attempt to access it from the Ethernet connection may allow you to bypass the error.

### TL;DR

My router doesn't support accessing its own network from an internal address. Change a rule or avoid accessing it from its external IP.